Mongoose _id is not working correctly for custom value instead of default value
Hay! I am working with mongoose where I have collection named tag and here is it's schema

const tagSchema = new Schema<ITag, ITagModel>(
  {
    _id: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
  },
);

export default tagSchema;

and I want to use it in my post collection here is it's schema
const postSchema = new Schema<IPost, IPostModel>(
  {
    content: {
      type: String,
      minLength: PostConstant.POST_CONTENT_MIN_LENGTH,
      maxLength: PostConstant.POST_CONTENT_MAX_LENGTH,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    tags: {
      type: [
        {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: TagsConstant.TAGS_COLLECTION_NAME,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  },
);

Now problem is that when I want to create a post first I am creating tags based on the post tag like that
postSchema.statics.createPost = async (payload: ICreatePost) => {
  try {
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
    let { tags } = payload;

    try {
      if (tags) {
        (tags as unknown as Array<ITag>) = tags.map((tag: string) => ({
          _id: tag,
        }));

        await TagModel.insertMany(tags, {
          ordered: false,
        });
        /* 
          {ordered:false} because if any of the tag exist in tag collection then ingnore it instead of stoping the process 
        */
      }
    } catch (error) {
      /*  */
    }

    tags = payload.tags;

    return await PostModel.create({
      ...payload,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    errorHandler(error);
  }
};

here my plan is I will create tag based on given tags if any of the tag not exist in collection then it will be create. and I have named tagSchema _id as tag name so that if I assign this _id in any other schema then I will get the tags list without populating the tag collection. but here it is showing that error
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Post validation failed: tags.0: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value \"[ 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3' ]\" (type string) at path \"tags.0\" because of \"CastError\"",
    "error": {}
}

As my knowledge mongoose automatically convert any string _id into ObjectId, it working for only mongoose auto generated _id but not working for my custom _id. How can I do this type of work that it auto convert my custom _id and insert in tags field in post collection.
I am trying use custom _id and use it in relation of referencing.

ObjectId needs to be of specific format https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

As per the mondodb documentation :

_id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array or regex. If the _id contains subfields, the subfield names cannot begin with a ($) symbol

Mongoose will not automatically cast 'String' to 'ObjectID'. In your tag schema _id is a String and in post schema it is ObjectID which is causing the issue. You need to change the tags type to string in your post schema.
